# Way to make Parent Folder View Style automatically be applied to subfolders?

Tags: windows, windows-11

Is there a way to set the View Style of the Explorer window to be always by default determined by the parent Folder's Viewstyle?

What I mean is let's say you change a certain folder to List... then all subfolders and subfolders of subfolders, etc. should be List now also.

I mean is there a way to do this automatically? not have to go and change the settings on each Parent folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mean is there a way to do this automatically? not have to go and
> change the settings on each Parent folder.

Automatically? No. Windows File Explorer does not work that way.

Permanently?  No.  Again, not the way File Explorer Works.

**What you can do.**

Open File Explorer to a Folder that looks how you wish. This could include C: assuming you wish to make everything look like your main file tree.

Then in File Explorer options, click the View Tab and then Click on "Apply to Folders"

This works but you occasionally need to do this again.

See the screen shot.

[image: Windows 11 File Explorer Options]

.

(If you need a more traditional File Explorer, I use xPlorer2 (zabkat) a lot. The setup can be fixed and saved and that is the ongoing setup until you change it).